# wdk how to migrate to v4 printer driver

Tags: c#, c++, printing, driver, wdk

My customer intends to migrate to V4 printer driver.

My current V3 printer driver package contains:- some CFG files

- User Interface DLL
- Printer Graphics DLL
- Help file .CHM
- INF file

What should I do for migrate to V4 printer architect?

Answer (score 0):

The V4 printer driver model is a refinement of the existing V3 printer driver model, and it was designed to support new scenarios.

New model still supports many technologies like XPSDrv, GPD, PPD, Autoconfiguration, and Bidi and also supports several new extensibility points.
With the exception of the rendering filters and user interface applications, all the other functional blocks are implemented by Microsoft. V4 print drivers rely heavily on data files (.gpd and .ppt files) and JavaScript for extensibility.

Some files including XPS filters (.dll files), Printer Config (.ppd and .gpd files), AutoConfig (GDL) and Bidi Extension (XML files) are almost same as were in V3 Driver model while as Printer Extension (.exe file), DevModeMap (.xml file), Constraint Scripts (JavaScript files), DriverEvents (.xml files), etc are completely new concepts and plugins in V4 printer driver mode. For more information see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/print/v4-printer-driver).

To build a sample V4 printer driver see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/print/build-a-v4-print-driver-in-visual-studio).

To put all in a nutshell:

- your Interface will not be a .dll file anymore. Instead in V4 printer
  driver, GUI is a .exe which is created in C#.
- your driver interface still is a .dll but the rendering filter
  concept have been    introduced. Note that for XPS-Direct printing
  there is no need for    any rendering filter and your
  "PipelineConfig.xml" file have to be    empty.
- You could keep your help file.
- About INF file see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/print/v4-driver-inf).